# How to check nil in nested value with EEx phoenix template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have following code.
I would like to show members point.
All members have point1 at least.
Some members have point2 or point3. It means some members have point2 or 3 are nil.

```
    <%= for member <- @members do %>
      <%= member.point1 %> <%= member.point2 %> <%= member.point3 %>
    <% end %>
```

My image is following.

```
   <%= unless is_nil(member.point2) %>
     <%= member.point2 %>
   <% end %>
```

I would like to avoid nil error in html.eex templates.
When I use ruby, it has nil check function.

Generally how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should clearly distinguish between `<%` and `<%=` template tags.

The former does evaluate the code, the latter evaluates it and *does print the outcome*. `EEx` dislikes `<%= nil %>` statements and `unless/1` returns `nil` if the condition is truthy and no `else` clause is provided.

That said, the below would work.

```rb
# ⇓⇓⇓ DO NOT PRINT IT OUT
<% unless is_nil(member.point2) %>
  <%= member.point2 %>
<% end %>
```

Also, you might trick the engine by converting `nil` to acceptable empty string.

```rb
<% for member <- @members, not is_nil(member) do %>
  <%= to_string(member.point1) %>
  <%= to_string(member.point2) %>
  <%= to_string(member.point3) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary 'or' operator (`||`) treats `nil` as a falsy value (along with `false`), so you can use it to convert `nil` (and `false`) to a specific value and leave other values as-is:

```
<%= member.point1 %> <%= member.point2 || "" %> <%= member.point3 || "" %>
```

This will convert `nil` and `false` to the empty string while leaving the value as-is if it's something else.